# How do liches regenerate from their phylacteries?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead

Whenever you kill a lich, its body is destroyed, and it regenerates next to its phylactery.

> ***Rejuvenation***. *If it has a phylactery*, a destroyed lich gains a new
>   body in 1d10 days, regaining all its hit points and becoming active
>   again. The new body appears within 5 feet of the phylactery. (SRD V 5.1, p. 325 {italics mine}

How does this happen?
Does its soul fly there when it dies?

#### Comparison to other monsters

I was reading about hags, and noticed that night hags can drop a Soul bag, which can trap evil souls.  If I were to obtain one, I thought that after I destroy a lich's body, I could trap it's soul in the bag while I hunt for the phylactery.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. It might worthwhile to clarify in the question the question's purpose. Is the intention to find out how the lich body is actually gained—besides, obviously, magic!—like, does the new body grow from the ground or does a local goat body spontaneously transform into a lich body? Or is the question *really* wondering if an effect that seizes a soul can stop a lich body forming? Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: I do, but it didn't specify. I asked my usual DM, but he didn't know either.

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what you're trying to *do* with this information? That will help us give you an answer that's useful.

Comment: I was reading about hags, and noticed that night hags can drop a Soul bag, which can trap evil souls. If I were to obtain one, I thought that after I destroy a lich's body, I could trap it's soul in the bag while I hunt for the phylactery.

Comment: So the question is really *Can a lich's soul be put in a hag's soul bag so as to prevent that lich from creating a new body?* Given that there are already answers to *this* question that have been met with a warm reception, you might want to pose that specific question as a new and separate question. (And, really, in the future,—so you know,— it's totally cool to ask *really specific* questions so that you can get the *exact* answers *you* want. There's no need to *generalize* the question for a wider audience—experts *will* find your question!)

Comment: I'm voting to close, but I think you've generated the more complete question here in the comments. I recommend editing your full intent into your original post and then I think it can be reopened.

Comment: I edited into your question your point about the hag soul bag.  that sort of detail belongs in your question, not in comments, which are ephemeral.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its soul doesn't go anywhere, it's already in the phylactery. The phylactery is a container for a Lich's soul.

As for the body, it's a magical construct, I imagine it takes a while for the lich to build up the required energy to manifest/summon/create? a new vessel capable of withstanding its sheer power.

Answer (score 7):

From the *Monster Manual* entry on the lich:

> When a lich's body is broken by accident or assault, the will and mind of the lich drains from it, leaving only a lifeless corpse behind.  Within days, a new body reforms next to the lich's phylactery, coalescing out of glowing smoke that issues from the device.

That's the extent of the RAW. It may help, however, to think of the process as similar to *magic jar*, save that there is no limit to its range and the lich creates their own body rather than stealing another.